# Jquery - Split Url and add class to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I need get the url, split it in words and add those class to body.
Example of my url (sometimes it contais `?` and `#`):
https://example.com/?query_type_cor=or&filtering=1&filter_cor=amarelo&filter_estilo=polo&filter_tamanho=gg

I want all words has class in body:
`query_type` `or` `filtering` `1` `filter_cor` `amarelo` `filter_estilo` `polo` `filter_tamanho` `gg`

I tried:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
       $('body'). 
});
```

And I get this answear in stack, but it didn't splitted the words.

```
function updateBodyClasses() {

  var classNames = [];

  // Use `.split()` to separate each key/value pair in the query by `&`
  window.location.search.split('&')
    // and loop over the results
    .forEach(function(c) {

      // Now split each pair by '='
      var pair = c.split['='];

      // Add the value to the left of the '=' 
      if (pair.length > 0) {
        classNames.push(pair[0]);

        // if there are values on the right of the '='...
        if (pair.length > 1) {

          // ... split them by ',' and loop through them
          pair[1].split(',').forEach(function(t) {
            classNames.push(t);
          });      
        }
      }
    });

    // Now append those classNames to the body
    $('body').addClass(classNames.join(' '));
}

// If your ajax plugin modifies the url via HTML5 history api...
$(window).on('popstate', updateBodyClasses);


// Update classes on page load
$(window).on('load', updateBodyClasses);

// If the ajax plugin modifies the url using window.location.replace()
// you'll need to check on an interval whether things have changed
// and update accordingly. the following example does this every 1000 milliseconds (or every second)

setInterval(updateBodyClasses, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are going too long**

First remove the url till `?|#` including it.
Split using `& | =`
use a for each function on the array and add each to body's class list

#### Code

`var url=window.location.href;` -> This will store the current url to `url`
`url=url.replace(/[^?#]*[?#]/,'');` -> this will remove the part before `?|#` including it
`url=url.split(/[&=]/);` -> This will split it on `& | =` it's result is an array
`url.forEach(x => document.body.classList.add(x));` -> Add all entries to body's classlist

```js
var url=window.location.href;
url=url.replace(/[^?#]*[?#]/,'');
url=url.split(/[&=]/);
url.forEach(x => document.body.classList.add(x));
```

Comment: Done!! @Sagar V